# A slight extension of The Directional Derivative Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

In Advanced Calculus 2nd edition by Patrick Fitzpatrick, he writes the following:

[image]

The part I don't follow is how he gets $\frac{d}{dt}[f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{p})]$ in (13.25). I understand the right hand side $\langle\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{p},\mathbf{p}\rangle$ as being the result of taking $\langle\nabla f(\mathbf{x}),\mathbf{p}\rangle$ and substituting $\mathbf{x}$ with $\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{p}$ but I don't understand how $\frac{d}{dt}[f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{p})]$ is the result of taking $\left.\frac{d}{dt}[f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{p})]\right|_{t=0}$ and performing the same substitution.

How does he arrive at the left hand side of (13.25)?

Comment: Btw, when they write "provided that the segment between $x$ and $x+tp$ lies in $\mathcal O$", I think it should really be "between $x$ and $x+p$". That way, when $0\le t\le1$ we have $x+tp \in \mathcal O$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of $t$ as a constant and insert $\newcommand{\x}{\mathbf x}\newcommand{\p}{\mathbf p}\x+t\p$ in place of $\x$ in (13.24). Since the variable $t$ is now taken, let's take the limit in $s$, giving
$$
\frac{d}{ds}f(\x+t\p+s\p)\bigl\vert_{s=0} = \langle\nabla f(\x+t\p),\p\rangle.
$$
If we define $t'=t+s$, the LHS becomes
$$ \begin{split}
\frac{d}{ds}f(\x+t\p+s\p)\bigl\vert_{s=0}
&= \frac{d}{ds}f(\x+(t+s)\p)\bigl\vert_{s=0} \\
&= \frac{d}{dt'}f(\x+t'\p)\bigl\vert_{t'=t} \\
&= \frac{d}{dt}f(\x+t\p).
\end{split} $$

Comment: Don't you have to invoke the chain rule for the step where $[(d/ds)f(\mathbf{x}+(t+s)\mathbf{p})]_{s=0}=[(d/dt')f(\mathbf{x}+t'\mathbf{p})]_{t'=t}$? The chain rule isn't proved until two chapters later and uses this result that we are trying to prove in its proof. How can this be proved without invoking the chain rule?

Comment: @user109923 Yes, you can see that step as using the chain rule, but you only use the 1d version (that's surely available at this point in the book, right?). It's 1d because $g(t'):=f(\mathbf{x} + t' \mathbf{p})$ and $t'(s)=t+s$ are both $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Alternatively, this change of variable is such a simple case that it follows immediately from the definition of differentiation without needing to prove the full chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Given a function $\phi : (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to \mathbb R, t \mapsto \phi(t)$, we have
$$\phi'(0) = \frac{d  \phi}{dt}(0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\phi(h) - \phi(0)}{h} . $$
It is usual to write
$$\phi'(0) = \frac{d  \phi}{dt}(0)  = \frac{d}{dt} \phi(t) \mid_{t=0} . \tag{1}$$
Applying this to $\phi(t) = f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p)$, we define the directional derivative as
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf p}(\mathbf x)  = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf x + h\mathbf p) - f(\mathbf x)}{h} = \frac{d}{dt} f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p) \mid_{t=0} . \tag{2}$$
Formula 13.20 says that
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf p}(\mathbf x)  = \langle \nabla f(\mathbf x), \mathbf p\rangle . \tag{3}$$
$(2)$ and $(3)$ give you formula 13.24. Substituting $\mathbf x$ with $\mathbf x + t\mathbf p$ in $(3)$ gives us
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf p}(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p)  = \langle \nabla f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p), \mathbf p\rangle . \tag{4}$$

But what does the formula
$$\frac{d}{dt} f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p)  = \langle \nabla f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p), \mathbf p\rangle \tag{13.25}$$
mean and how does it follow from the above considerations? The essential point is to understand what  $\frac{d}{dt} f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p)$ means. **Recalling $\phi(t) = f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p)$, it stands for $\phi'(t)$.** Thus 13.25 says nothing else than
$$\phi'(t) = \langle \nabla f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p), \mathbf p\rangle $$
which yields 13.24 if we take $t = 0$.

Let us observe that *naively* substituting $\mathbf x$ with $\mathbf x' = \mathbf x+t\mathbf p$ in $(2)$ is not a good idea because the result is misleading:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf p}(\mathbf x+t\mathbf p)  =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p + h\mathbf p) - f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p)}{h} = \frac{d}{dt} f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p + t\mathbf p) \mid_{t=0} . \tag{2'}$$
The problem here is that $t$ is used ambiguously in the RHS. It is correct to write
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf p}(\mathbf x')  =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf x' + h\mathbf p) - f(\mathbf x')}{h} = \frac{d}{dt} f(\mathbf x' + t\mathbf p) \mid_{t=0} . \tag{2''}$$
Here $\mathbf x'$ is a *fixed vector* (which contains a *fixed* $t$ in hidden form) and the $t$ in $\mathbf x' + t\mathbf p$ denotes the *variable* used for differentiating the function $f(\mathbf x' + t\mathbf p)$.

But the first equation in $(2'')$ is the key to prove 13.25:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf p}(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p) =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p + h\mathbf p) - f(\mathbf x + t\mathbf p)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\phi(t +h) - \phi(t)}{h} = \phi'(t) .$$
Combine this with $(4)$.

Comment: But how does that last line equal $(d/dt)[f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{p})]$?

Comment: @user109923 See my edit.

Comment: What does $\nabla\phi(t)$ mean? $\phi(t)$ is a function of only one variable, so $\nabla\phi(t)$ would be a 1-dimensional vector and the inner product $\langle\nabla\phi(t),\mathbf{p}\rangle$ would not be defined unless $\mathbf{p}$ was also 1-dimensional.

Comment: @user109923 You are right, I corrected that point.